# ios NSUserDefaults storing a username. Can a user edit this?

Tags: iphone, ios, nsuserdefaults

Right now I have a username being stored in NSUserDefaults and the password in a keychain.  While I know everything is stored in plain text in NSUserDefaults, could an end-user also change this stored value?  The username is used throughout the application to retrieve data from a server.  My fear is that if an end-user can change this value, they would be able to become other users.

So is NSUserDefaults readable and writable or just readable by the end-user?

Comment: They would need a matching password too, don't they?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That depends. Your average end-user will not be able to, but an average user with a Jailbroken iDevice could.

Your `NSUserDefauls` is a plist stored in `~/Applications/{APPLICATION_UUID}/Library/Preferences/com.mydomain.myapp.plist` in a plain XML format, making it very easy for an end user to edit, and if they are a serious jailbreaker in the first place, they probably have a plist editor on their iPhone to start with (iFile, iFinder, etc.)

Sensitive data should be stored in an encrypted binary format via `fread()` / `fwrite()` in my opinion.

Comment: If I store the username in the keychain as well would I not have to worry about it being changed?

Comment: @user1108720 I don't know, I've never used keychains on iOS, but if MacOS is any idea as to how it works, then yes, it is probably extremely easy to edit.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer is no, the user cannot change the values saved in the NSUserDefaults.

Medium answer, the values are saved to a plist file that is visible in plain text if the device is plugged in and you have a working copy of Xcode. Or by some other means via jailbreaking, but it generally isn't a concern.

In regards to the comments in the accepted answer about using the iOS Keychain, the user cannot change that either. You can find many examples showing you how to store the username and/or password using the KeychainWrapper files provided by Apple. I recently converted my app from a salted/hashed token generated from the username and password to storing them directly in the keychain. I think it is ultimately the safest, most secure way of storing user credentials. In my opinion anyway.